# Plotting a function with constraints

Tags: plotting

I have three variables `x,y,z` and a function `f[x_, y_] = x Sqrt[x^4 + y^4]`. I want to plot this function and also the regions `z >= x + y - 1; z <= 1 - x + y; z <= x + y - 1; z >= 1 + x - y;`. How can one show all this in single plot?

Comment: Try with `Plot3D[function, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, region]`.

Comment: Or you can stuff your inequalities into `ImplicitRegion[]`, and use that in `Plot3D[]`.

Comment: Seems some problem: region = ImplicitRegion[{z >= x + y - 1, z <= 1 - x + y, 
    z <= x + y - 1, z >= 1 + x - y}, {x, y, z}];
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, region]]    tells "Function[{x,y,z},region][Identity[#1],Identity[#2],Identity[#3]]& \
must be a Boolean function."